# Do we expect baseline (all features) and selected features to perform the same with decision trees?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm using sklearn's decision tree for a binary class problem. However it turns out that after optimizing everything (optimizing hyper parameters and using the optimal number of selected features), the best I can do is get an accuracy and f1-score that's as good as baseline (no feature selection and use all features).

Sure now it's less messy (less features), and the code runs faster. But is this expected? Or is the point of feature selection to improve performance metrics of the classifier?

Comment: depends entirely on the dataset. what is the dimensionality to begin with? has the data been cleaned? are you seeing these results just on the training data (have you even split the dataset?), in which case you might just be overfitting. many other considerations, but taking your question in complete isolation to all of that... yes, if you can achieve similar or better performance after reducing the feature space then you're on the right path.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Feature selection will mostly give you performance benefits and might help a little against overfitting if relevant. It's not really supposed to improve the training metrics as you are essentially trying to solve the same problem with less information in your hands.

It doesn't mean you shouldn't do it though. If you can achieve the same performance with fewer features - use fewer features :)